# mySql custom select and display

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to get custom data from my wordpress database, but my knowledge in sql ist that good. Could some one help me?

Please look at my example. 
[image]

I am trying to echo out image names (**filename**) from table (**wp_ngg_pictures**) that have galleryid = **2**

So in this example I would get the list of :

- bildes-140.jpg
- bildes-127.jpg
- bildes-133.jpg
- bildes-152.jpg
- And so on....

Comment: `SELECT filename FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = 2`. Barebones beginner SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your using PHP all you would do is connect to your database and then do something like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = 2")or die (mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo $row['filename'];
        }
```

If you wanted more specific results it would be a little different.
Fixed the errors.. sorry bout that, still learning myself.

Comment: You'll need to fetch results from `$result` first. This won't give any data back.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT filename from wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should Loop though all galleries with id of 2 and echo out the id and file name.

---

```
$GetAlbum=2;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM YOURDATABASE.wp_ngg_pictures WHERE galleryid LIKE '%".$GetAlbum."%'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! Could not get gallery Databse.');
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$gallery=mysql_result($result,$i,"galleryid");
$galleryImg=mysql_result($result,$i,"filename");
echo 'ID '.$gallery.' File '.$galleryImg.'';
}
```